# Handling loading states of multiple threads in Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my Android app i'd like the user to be able to see when a task is running in the background.

These tasks can be either network calls or database operations, running on separate background threads.

There is a single indeterminate `ProgressBar` in the `Activity`, which i would like to show if any background tasks are running, and hide it otherwise.

I've searched for solutions to this and people seem to use `LiveData` for similar purposes.

So i figured i'd create a `LiveData` in the `ViewModel` of the `Activity` that represents the current loading state of the app, something like this:

```
val loadingState = MutableLiveData<State>()
```

Whenever i'm starting or finishing a task, i'd post the appropriate value to this `LiveData`:

```
// starting background operation
loadingState.postValue(Status.LOADING)
```

And i'd observe on it from the `Activity` and show/hide the `ProgressBar` according to the current state:

```
loadingState.observe(this, Observer { status ->
    when (status) {
        Status.LOADING -> showProgressBar()
        Status.IDLE -> hideProgressBar()
    }
}
```

My problem is i don't know how to handle this when there are multiple tasks running on multiple threads.

For example:

- **A** task starts and sets the status to `LOADING` (correct)
- **B** task starts (the status is already `LOADING` so nothing happens) (correct)
- **A** task finishes and sets the status to `IDLE`, however **B** is still running (wrong)

  The `ProgressBar` will be hidden even though **B** is still in progress
- **B** task finishes,  but the status is already `IDLE` (wrong)

I thought i could maintain a `Collection` of `LiveData` objects (as in a separate `LiveData` for each task) but it seems really cumbersome.

Is there an idiomatic way to handle this?

(Java answers are welcome as well)

Comment: First idea that comes to mind is to centralize all the the tasks creation in a need a task manager that keeps count or even instances of the tasks and offers an API for querying and callbacks when tasks have started/finished.

Answer (score 1):

i have a simple idea

in the view model use variable like that

```
var numberOFThreads = 0
```

and replace this line

```
loadingState.postValue(Status.LOADING)
```

with

```
if(numberOFThreads == 0){
loadingState.postValue(Status.LOADING)
}else{
numberOFThreads++
}

and
if(numberOFThreads == 0){
loadingState.postValue(Status.IDLE )
}else{
numberOFThreads--
}
```